# Long requests block Tomcat server

Tags: java, multithreading, tomcat

I have a Java application running on a Tomcat server

For example I have two types of requests

1. Short request - completed in 100 milliseconds
2. Long request - completed in 1 minute

For example, my Tomcat server has 16 threads.

If 16 long requests are sent, the web server will be blocked for all users for 1 minute

How to deal with this situation? How can I prevent long requests from blocking the entire server and consuming the entire thread pool?

Comment: Netty and NIO can help here.  See if you can substitute it for Tomcat.

Comment: Somewhat of a workaround, which depends on what exactly the requests are doing, but you can schedule the job for execution in another thread (ExecutorService for example) and return a url to the client, where he can check the status of the job.

Comment: And, in addition to Chaosfire's comment, you can always utilize the Servlet async facility (e.g. look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/servlets012.htm)). Setting up Tomcat that the async Servlet execution uses a different thread pool than than of the connector might be tricky (I do not know if/how it is possible).

Comment: Do we already know if the request is longRunning request or a shortOne.If that is the case we can create 2 threadpools taking care of each type of request